# Why can't we have more options when marking something as unsalvageable in Triage on SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, close-reasons, triage

When I'm reviewing, if I do end up marking something as unsalvageable, I end up having to use too broad or unclear what you're asking in cases where the grammar or language in general is all over the shop. We get:

- duplicate of
- off-topic because...
- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

But, I think there should be another option of unclear grammar or language, unreadable or similar. It's not necessarily that it's too broad, it *is* unclear what you're asking, but often not in a technical sense, purely grammatically.

Does anyone else have any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: These are close reasons... if it's not salvageable, it needs to be flagged as VLQ. Are you asking whether it would be possible to add the flagging options to the review queue?

Comment: I guess I am. I'll look into what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: @Catija This question appears to be about the Triage review queue, which, IIRC, is on Stack Overflow only. There, users have the options of "Looks OK", "Requires Editing", and "Unsalvagable" to review a post. "Unsalvagable" opens the Flag/Close dialog.

Comment: If I'm correct that this is about Triage, then this question would be better off on Meta Stack Overflow, since SO is currently the only site with this queue. You'd get better responses there.

Comment: @Kendra That is certainly possible. I'm not familiar with SO at all. If you are correct that it's SO specific, I would agree that this question would be better served on MSO.

Comment: I'll ask there. Thanks for the feedback, everyone.

Comment: @Catija while better asked on MSO, if posted here [we should not close it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246116/in-triage-queue-if-in-my-20th-review-of-the-day-i-click-looks-ok-and-it-gives?noredirect=1#comment906155_246116).

Comment: @ShadowWizard "it isn't a big deal" doesn't mean "we should not close it"... There's no reason for there to be duped questions on MSO and MSE. The implication of the OP's last comment was that they were going to dupe the question on MSO.

Comment: @Catija so guess each of us understood what bluefeet said in a different way. I took it as "it is not off topic, so should not be closed".

Comment: @ShadowWizard "Should not close it" is a directive that means, "leave it open"... on the other hand, "It isn't a big deal" means "it doesn't *need* to be closed"... This question doesn't seem to have ever been asked on MSO, that I can see... but if it had, it should certainly be closed since that's standard for identical questions posted on two different sites, particularly when posted by the same user.

Answer (score 7):

If the grammatical problems with the question are so severe that you really cannot understand what is being asked, then you should be voting to close the question as, "unclear what you're asking".  That's literally exactly what the close reason is for.

If there are grammatical or formatting problems that make it annoying or more time consuming to read, but where with a bit of time and effort you can figure out what is being asked, then the question doesn't merit closure, and isn't unsalvageable.  You should mark the question as needing editing, because the question can be fixed by the community.